# Wrapping the footnote text to the margins of a column (using multicol)

Tags: footnotes

I'm interested in wrapping the footnote text to the bounds of a single column when using the multicolumn package.

I am aware that in the example image they are most likely using the \author command. But I want a similar style of footnote that conforms exactly with the column margins, as opposed to the one I have that runs horizontally across the page.

[image]

Thank-you for reading.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  the `multicol` packate is not (at least at present) able to place footnotes in just one column.  from the abstract to the documentation: "Footnotes ... will be placed at the bottom of the page and not under each column."  this is because the ability to balance the columns and change the number of columns on the same page makes it impossible to know in which column a footnote was triggered.  the `[twocol]` option is what provides the layout you are looking for.

Comment: If Barbara Beeton's comment doesn't properly address your issue, please provide (i) a fuller picture of the desired output. It is unclear from the top image how the pieces of text are connected. For instance, it looks as though the portion of text at top right has a footnotemark in it: `men).¹ T` ..? (Where is the corresponding footnote?) Also, (ii) please provide some basic and minimal code for people to work from: `\documentclass` down to `\end{document}`, but which loads no unnecessary packages and creates no unrelated commands.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for both of your inputs. The problem was indeed with multicol as suggested by Barbara. I've got it fixed now by adding the \twocolumn to the document.

Comment: Any updates? A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is still missing.